# SSRS reports pdf version having printing issues

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We have been trying to export SSRS reports into pdfs and trying to print them.
The pdf on printing prints smaller sizes of the fonts.
The digital version looks right. We have used custom sizes on some of the reports and some use A4. 
But this problem occurs on both. Are there any compatibility issues that we need to verify or any config changes. Pls suggest.
Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your margins and report width.

The report Body width + the margins must be equal to or less than the Paper Size width.

You may be going over the margins for your printer and your PDF reader is scaling it to fit on a page.

You can check by looking at the PRINT options and making sure that it doesn't Shrink Oversized pages or Fit to page. Mine has an **Actual Size** setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried this. But we still do have issues printing some of the reports. Right now we are tweaking the margins and the fonts to make sure each report prints fine.
We wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve this.